# how can I read multiple text files in matlab?

Tags: matlab, list, file-io, text-files, textscan

if possible please let me know that how I can read different text files in Matlab .
considering that there is 33 txt files that every one should process.
it is my code which has error. :(

```
 textFilename = cell(1,33);
        id = cell(1,33);
        for k=1:33;
        textFilename{k} = fullfile('C:\Users\Desktop\SentimentCode\textfiles',['file' num2str(k)     '.txt']);
        id{k} = fopen(textFilename{k},'rt'); 
        str{k} = textscan(id{k},'%s%s'); 

    end                                                      
    str(str == '.') = '';
    str(str == '_') = '';
    str(str == '-') = '';


% Remove numbers from text
    T =regexprep(str, '[\d]', ' ');                                  

  and my error is :   ??? Undefined function or method 'eq' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in ==> Untitled9 at 23
str(str == '.') = '';
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: many thanks for your reply .. I edited my post and add some lines more and the errors I appreciate you for your answering

Comment: and I used of fclose(id{k}) at the end of my code .

Comment: and the explanation of the error also is : The size of the indicated variable or array appears to be changing with each loop iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current edit your error seem more directed to the removal of . - and _ characters.
The == comparasion works better with character strings while textscan returns a cell

Instead of

```
str(str == '.') = '';
str(str == '_') = '';
str(str == '-') = '';
```

try using

```
regexprep(str,'(\.|-|_)','')
```

to replace all at once  (the '\.' is needed as '.' is a special character).
This works on **cellstrings** so depending on how deep your cell structure goes you might need to call it within a for loop, str{k},str{k}{1}, str{k}{i} etc...
An alternative could be to look at [cellfun](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html)
or/and [strjoin](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/strjoin.html)... depending on how your data are arranged in the files.

Answer (score 0):

Just by looking at the example code:

```
extFilename{k} = fullfile(..);
```

should be

```
textFilename{k} = fullfile(...);
```

Also it is good idea to close the files after you read them: `fclose(id{k})`